# socket.io on nodejs - socket leave room does not work

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Using socket.io on nodejs I'm tryng to "change" a room depending some user behavior. To achive this:

1. get the current room
2. leave the room
3. join the new room

Using string constants for the room name everything works fine but using variable it doesn't work. No error is displayed but socket doesn't leave the room. In the code above log "room before2 and "room after" print the same list and currentRoom is equal to a socket.adapter.rooms key entry

```
var newroom = "funnyroom" + room;   
//get the current from room list                                                                             
var currentRoom = getCurrentRomm(rooms);
logger.debug("room before " + Object.keys(socket.adapter.rooms));
socket.leave(currentRoom, function (err){
    logger.debug("error " + err);
    logger.debug("room after " + Object.keys(socket.adapter.rooms));
});
socket.join(newroom);
```